# The algorithm for the generic va_arg(l, type) implementation

Tags: c, x86-64, variadic-functions, calling-convention, abi

I am now looking into the implementation detail of the va_arg macro which is defined in the AMD64 ABI documentation, and what confuses me is the second step of the algorithm as I showed below. My question is that why do we need to compute the `num_gp` here since the "type" should be passed in each register if it can be fit into that register, otherwise, it should be passed via stack. So, in this case, the `num_gp` here should always be one, right? Or am I misunderstanding anything?

Please refer to this [link](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/x86-64-psABI-1.0.pdf) for the pdf version of the ABI documentation, and the algorithm is defined on page **57**.

[image]

Comment: check actual compiler output, for compilers known to follow the x86-64 System V ABI: https://godbolt.org/z/Y6dEPGfdf shows GCC reading struct members from RDI and RSI.

Answer (score 3):

Your premise is wrong. Type can be passed in several registers if it doesn't fit into one.

For example, a 128-bit sized type can be passed in `rdi` and `rsi`.